# What solr -s option does?

Tags: solr, lucene

What does the -s option in the below solr command do?

```
solr start -p 8983 -s "../example/techproducts/solr"
```

Second, if I run the command `solr -e techproducts` as mentioned in this http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html#Install after the solr is already started it gives an error that "*an instance of solr is already running*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sets the `solr.solr.home` system property; Solr will create core
>   directories under this directory. This allows you to run multiple Solr
>   instances on the same host while reusing the same server directory set
>   using the -d parameter.
>
> If set, the specified directory should contain a `solr.xml` file, unless
>   `solr.xml` exists in ZooKeeper. The default value is `server/solr`.
>
> This parameter is ignored when running examples (`-e`), as the
>   `solr.solr.home` depends on which example is run.

-- from [Lucidworks - Solr Control Script Reference](https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion-server/4.0/solr-reference-guide/7.2.1/solr-control-script-reference.html)

Comment: As per the instructions in this link http://www.mkyong.com/solr/apache-solr-hello-world-example/ I set the solr home property in my Windows Path variable I am not able to start Solr with error as "solr.xml file is missing". Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: I'll answer my doubts in the comment above. Setting SOLR_HOME in the Windows Environment variable should be as "E:\solr-xx\server\solr. Whereas the Path variable of Windows should point to the bin directory of solr installation, i.e. E:\solr-xx\bin.